# How to fetch offline message from pubsub node in smack

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe, openfire, smack

I am using smack.  How Do I fetch an offline message from a pubsub node? I tried using OfflineMessageManager to fetch the message, but it did not work.

Comment: Please post some code to show what you have tried. This will be very helpful in answering your question, as it is a little vague at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, was the node configured to deliver messages to offline subscribers?  If not there are none to retrieve.

Does your server have offline messages turned on?  The pubsub messages should be no different than any other offline message, so there is nothing special about how to retrieve them.

If you simply want to get the messages that are in the node, and the node is persistent, you can get messages directly from the node by using

```
myLeafNode.getItems();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to turned on offline message? I am having the same issue and don't know how to make it work. I am using **Tigase Server**